# IsDisabled attached property

Tags: wpf, attachedbehaviors, disabled-control

How can we attach a property to a known property like 'IsDisabled'? For instance, I would like another property to take over and change some things when my control is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually just use [`Triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Trigger.aspx) on `IsEnabled == false` with some [`Setters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.aspx) for that.